# Error when trying to install colored http gem

Tags: ruby, http, rubygems, ruby-native-extensions

I'm trying to install the gem colored http but I got this error when I run "gem install colored http" :

```
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -rrubygems /Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR\=/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/http-parser-1.2.3 RUBYLIBDIR\=/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/http-parser-1.2.3
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/compile_task.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/ext/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/compile_task.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/ext/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi-compiler/compile_task
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/http-parser-1.2.3/ext/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/pierrecohen/.gem/gems/http-parser-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/pierrecohen/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/http-parser-1.2.3/gem_make.out
1 gem installed
```

Can somebody help me :) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Top google result](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/870) -- Have you tried this? Does it help?

Comment: Are you having ruby-dev, ruby and build-essential installed?  
For Debian, try the following

```
sudo apt-get install -y ruby-dev ruby build-essential
```